# How to merge multiple rows into one row based on null values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Please can you help by providing me with a sample query showing how to merge multiple rows into one row based on null values in oracle. Please find the attached images.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY` to get one row per cloumn1/cloumn2 combination. Use e.g. MAX() to pick the cloumn3 etc value.

```
select cloumn1, cloumn2, max(cloumn3), max(cloumn4), max(cloumn5)
from tablename
group by cloumn1, cloumn2
```